# package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 5026 pos 12: 'child == _child': is not true

Tags: flutter

I am using `riverpod` and  `a consumerWidget` and this is the sample code offending:
I am trying to provide an `ImageProvider` to my consumer widget but end up with the error `'child == _child': is not true.`

This is the provider:

```
final path = Provider<ImageProvider<Object>?>((ref) {
  final box = Hive.box('onboarding');
  final path = box.get('photo');
  if (path == null) {
    return const AssetImage("assets/images/user7.jpg");
  }
  return FileImage(File(path));
});
```

And this is the consumer widget that:

```
class Home extends ConsumerWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final image = ref.watch(path);

    return account.when(
        loading: () => const CircularProgressIndicator(),
        error: (error, stackTrace) => Text(error.toString()),
        data: (instance) {
          return Scaffold(
          ...
          child: CircleAvatar(   
                            backgroundImage: image, // <- this is the offending line, 
                            maxRadius: 20,
                          ),)
```

This is part of the stack trace:

```
The relevant error-causing widget was
MaterialApp
main.dart:30
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
....
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: exact my problem - if you found an answer - PLEASE, PLEASE - let me know

Comment: Generally speaking, the error means you are trying to load the same widget twice but for this error, I changed the image provider and it worked.

Comment: Margach Chris, thanks a lot!